# Change background color of bootstrap navbar collapse without a delay

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js

I'm trying to overwrite the background colour of the collapsed menu bar which I successfully did. However, the problem is that the colour applies only when the collapsed menu is fully opened. I'm trying to do this with bootstrap-vue in a Nuxt project. The change to the navbar styling was made using a css file within the assets folder which I'm not sure if it's the right way to do.

How do I make the background colour appear as the dropdown animates down? thanks.

I've made a replicate of my project code on JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/tandeman/ae2s9104/37/) for you to have a look. 
All the code required to change the background was

```
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #7E6551;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a style for `.navbar-collapse.collapsing` to apply background colour when the menu is in expanding or collapsing.

For you it would look like:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapsing {
  background-color: #7E6551;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Full JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sthotakura/942jreda/1/).